# C# SQL INSERT not appearing in database table "no errors or exceptions thrown"

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I have been trying to figure out why my inserts are not showing up in my database table. i have done step through many times, i see no error and i get no exceptions. I am new to using databases so maybe there is something i can see, any help will be appreciated. Thanks

```
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [dbo].[EmployeeInfo] 
(Id, name, password) VALUES (@Id, @name, @password)", connection)) {
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Id++);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);

     try {
       connection.Open();
       //rows effected
       int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

       MessageBox.Show("User saved");

     } catch (SqlException ex) {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.GetType().ToString());

     } finally {
       nameBox.Clear();
       passwordBox.Clear();
       connection.Close();
     }
}
```

This is my connection string from config file

```
<connectionStrings> 
   <add name="SBPA.Properties.Settings.EmployeeLoginConnectionString" 
        connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\EmployeeLogin.mdf;Integrated Security=True" 
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: You tagged the question "mysql", but you are using SQL Server syntax.  Could that be the problem?

Comment: Does `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` return a value that is greater than zero?

Comment: What does cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() returns? Secondly, does your inputs like name, password contains single quote/apostrophe? (Name like Mervin D'Mello) Check your input values.

Comment: Have you reviewed that your id column is not AUTO INCREMENT

Comment: Can you show how you are reading the connection strings from config file?

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the right database?

Comment: Check for triggers on the table. There may be an `INSTEAD OF` trigger on that table.

Comment: thank you all for the fast response. i was looking in the wrong place for updates. they were taking place in the copy of database in bin/debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay guys thanks you all for the response after a couple of hours i finally figured out there was nothing wrong in my code. The database that was being update was the one in the bin/debug  folder not the one i being referenced in my solution. I did not realize that all changes while working on a project are done to the copy in debug folder.

Comment: So since there are no upvoted answers on your question and it will not be useful for further visitors you might delete it.

Comment: if more people think i should delete i will. however i think it would be useful to some people who are not very familiar with how visual studios works with debugs ect.

Comment: It's your decision, my point of view is different, but it's a personal point of view ... let's see how the community will decide.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check these two things:

1. What is value of `i` you are getting  `int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`. if this is 1 then:
2. Are you are referring to right `.mdf` file while seeing inserted record or not? Because you have referred a connection string of attached db file.

Answer (score 0):

So I had this same problem, turns out I had a typo, the Sql statement was long, so I couldn't detect it easily, however in the bin directory a text file logged the error, so I could easily figure out where to correct[Bin folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPdgQ.png)  [error logged in txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSNX0.png)